# Am I Using Stringstream Wrong?

Tags: c++, xcode, g++, stringstream

I have a program that compiles in XCode. In that program, I am taking advantage of stringstream's ability to store values according to the type that they are being assigned to.

Eg) The user inputs a letter, a number, and a symbol separated by spaces in the console. I make a call to getline that gets all three values and stores them in a string. I then create a stringstream with that string's data and assign the values to some variables, a char, an int, and a char in this case. I compile and run within XCode and this works. Then, I take that same file in a terminal and call g++ -o executableName fileName.cpp. Here, I get an error.

Working Example:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string buffer;
    char letter;
    int number;
    char symbol;

    cout << "Enter (letter) (number) (symbol): ";
    getline(cin, buffer);

    stringstream(buffer) >> letter >> number >> symbol; //The error occurs here

    cout << letter << " " << number << " " << symbol << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I compile and run in XCode:

```
Enter (letter) (number) (symbol): B 145 #
B 145 #
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

I compile with g++:

```
$ g++ -o test main.cpp
main.cpp:14:26: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::stringstream' (aka 'basic_stringstream<char>') and 'int')
stringstream(buffer) >> letter >> number >> symbol;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~
```

and then follows all of this:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:789:1: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'char' to 'unsigned char *' for 2nd
>         argument
>   operator>>(basic_istream& __is, unsigned char* __s)
>   ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:797:1: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'char' to 'signed char *' for 2nd
>         argument
>   operator>>(basic_istream& __is, signed char* __s)
>   ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:804:1: note: candidate function [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::__1::char_traits] not viable:
>         no known conversion from 'std::__1::stringstream' (aka 'basic_stringstream') to 'basic_istream > &' for 1st argument
>   operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __is, _CharT& __c)
>   ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:832:1: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'char' to 'unsigned char &' for 2nd
>         argument
>   operator>>(basic_istream& __is, unsigned char& __c)
>   ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:840:1: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'char' to 'signed char &' for 2nd
>         argument
>   operator>>(basic_istream& __is, signed char& __c)
>   ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:220:20: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'char' to
>         'std::__1::basic_istream &(*)(std::__1::basic_istream &)' for 1st argument
>       basic_istream& operator>>(basic_istream& (*__pf)(basic_istream&))
>                      ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:224:20: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'char' to
>         'basic_ios >::char_type, std::__1::basic_istream >::traits_type> &(*)(basic_ios >::char_type, std::__1::basic_istream >::traits_type> &)' (aka 'basic_ios > &(*)(basic_ios > &)') for 1st argument
>       basic_istream& operator>>(basic_ios&
>                      ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:229:20: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'char' to
>         'std::__1::ios_base &(*)(std::__1::ios_base &)' for 1st argument
>       basic_istream& operator>>(ios_base& (*__pf)(ios_base&))
>                      ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:232:20: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'char' to
>         'basic_streambuf >::char_type, std::__1::basic_istream >::traits_type> *'
>         (aka 'basic_streambuf > *') for 1st argument
>       basic_istream& operator>>(basic_streambuf* __sb);
>                      ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:233:20: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'char' to 'bool &' for 1st argument
>       basic_istream& operator>>(bool& __n);
>                      ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:234:20: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'char' to 'short &' for 1st
>         argument
>       basic_istream& operator>>(short& __n);
>                      ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:235:20: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'char' to 'unsigned short &' for
>         1st argument
>       basic_istream& operator>>(unsigned short& __n);
>                      ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:236:20: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'char' to 'int &' for 1st argument
>       basic_istream& operator>>(int& __n);
>                      ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:237:20: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'char' to 'unsigned int &' for 1st
>         argument
>       basic_istream& operator>>(unsigned int& __n);
>                      ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:238:20: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'char' to 'long &' for 1st argument
>       basic_istream& operator>>(long& __n);
>                      ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:239:20: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'char' to 'unsigned long &' for 1st
>         argument
>       basic_istream& operator>>(unsigned long& __n);
>                      ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:240:20: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'char' to 'long long &' for 1st
>         argument
>       basic_istream& operator>>(long long& __n);
>                      ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:241:20: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'char' to 'unsigned long long &'
>         for 1st argument
>       basic_istream& operator>>(unsigned long long& __n);
>                      ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:242:20: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'char' to 'float &' for 1st
>         argument
>       basic_istream& operator>>(float& __f);
>                      ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:243:20: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'char' to 'double &' for 1st
>         argument
>       basic_istream& operator>>(double& __f);
>                      ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:244:20: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'char' to 'long double &' for 1st
>         argument
>       basic_istream& operator>>(long double& __f);
>                      ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:245:20: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'char' to 'void *&' for 1st
>         argument
>       basic_istream& operator>>(void*& __p);
>                      ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:740:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match '_CharT *' against 'char'
>   operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __is, _CharT* __s)
>   ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:1506:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_string' against 'char'
>   operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __is,
>   ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:1638:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'bitset<_Size>' against 'char'
>   operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __is, bitset<_Size>& __x)
>   ^
>   1 error generated.

Is my use of stringstream wrong? (as an aside, Why does XCode allow the code to compile while g++ does not? I thought XCode uses the same g++)

Comment: GCC 8 compiles the program without warnings using `-Wall` on Fedora 28. The program also seems to run OK. Maybe it is something related to OS X or LLVM.

Comment: @jww Thanks jww. I tested and verify that gcc 6.3 compiles it on my debian OS with no warnings also. That is interesting what you say about LLVM. I use g++ -v on my mac and see: Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2). I am not sure why there is anything about clang when I am trying to use gcc, but regardless, both should be in accordance with the standard.